# Laravel relation many to many with additional pivot

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

**Status Update**

I have implemented morph to many relationship type but how can I insert into the `addition` field?

The code for the polymorphic relation is:

```
public function mailmessages()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('Mailmessage','rel','mailmessage_rels','rel_id','mailmessage_rel_id')
                ->withPivot(['addition']);
}
```

**Original Post**

I have a Laravel project that uses many to many relations and in the pivot table I have additional field that describes the related model.
For example I have this mail message Model and this is the relation table `mailmessage_rels` Here is a brief overview:

```
+--------------------+------------------+
| Field              | Type             |
+--------------------+------------------+
| id                 | int(10) unsigned |
| mailmessage_rel_id | int(10) unsigned |
| rel_id             | varchar(36)      |
| rel_type           | varchar(36)      |
| addition           | varchar(255)     |
+--------------------+------------------+
```

Lets say I have a Contact model. In this Contact model I have `mailmessages` relation.

```
public function mailmessages()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Mailmessage','mailmessage_rels','rel_id','mailmessage_rel_id')
                    ->wherePivot('rel_type','Contact')
                    ->withPivot(['addition']);
    }
```

When I retrive information everything is OK, but when I try to create a relation(using attach) it does not write the `rel_type` field which actually is not what I want.  I use simply:

```
$contact->mailmessages()->attach($message);
```

Should I do the attachment manually or should I add some additional parameter to the code?

Comment: i think your basic requirement Polymorphic Relations. try to implement it.

Comment: Ok I have successfully implemented `morphToMany` relationship. Thank you! But what about the `addition` field how can I write it?

Comment: Great, Addition field not a big problem now. you can use:
 `$user->roles()->attach(1, ['expires' => $expires]);`
`$user->roles()->sync([1 => ['expires' => true]]);`
`User::find(1)->roles()->save($role, ['expires' => $expires]);`

Comment: @SafoorSafdar the `$user->roles()->attach(1, ['expires' => $expires]);` does not seams to work. I mean it is part of the official [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#inserting-related-models) but still.

Comment: its should work, what seems to be issue? display error

Comment: Ok it works I was having issue with an `if` statement so It works. Thank you for your answer. Post short answer below and I will mark it as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement, I blieve you have to update your relation to Polymorphic Relations. 
and than to access other attributes try one of them method.

```
$user->roles()->attach(1, ['expires' => $expires]); 
$user->roles()->sync([1 => ['expires' => true]]); 
User::find(1)->roles()->save($role, ['expires' => $expires]);
```

If you still facing some dificulties to handle that requirement let me know.