# Laravel How to detach from a model with additional info

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'd like to detach a model using a pivot that has additional info. for attaching, this works well:

```
$user->badges()->attach($badge_id, ['additional' => $addInfo]);
```

What I would like to do is

```
$user->badges()->detach($badge_id, ['additional' => $addInfo]);
```

but this unfortunately removes all the badges with $badge_id.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel relation many to many with additional pivot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30982382/laravel-relation-many-to-many-with-additional-pivot)

Comment: @SafoorSafdar I don't see any mention in that thread to detaching with pivot

Comment: however, when you detach, other data attributes automatically detach. you dont need to detach separatly.

Answer (score 0):

Attach does have an option to provide additional attributes, detach does not. See the api reference:

http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.html#method_detach

```
int detach(int|array $ids = array(), bool $touch = true)
```

You could however do something like:

```
$user->badges()->where('id',$badge)->where('additional', $addInfo)->update(['user_id' => null]);
```

Assuming it's badges.user_id and additional is just a value.

Comment: this is more or less what I'm doing now - out of cusriousity - why nullify the user_id and not delete?

Comment: Detach means removing the relationship with the object. Not removal.

Comment: Of course - I meant why not delete the relationship... Detach definitely deletes the row in the pivot table which doesn't leave empty relationships in the table...